# Can a woman cut a man's hair (and vice versa)?

Tags: fiqh, hair

The haircut shops near me have mostly women cutting the hair. Can I let a female cut my hair?

Comment: Are you assuming the women are not non-mahram?!

Comment: assuming you are a male : no , do not let a female cut your her.

Comment: Re: "vice versa": a woman is meant to cover her hair in front of non-mahrams.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes if these persons are married or mahrams there's no harm in doing so for the hair of the head. (The matter for married people is discussed in this fatwa in Arabic islamweb #[176041](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=176041))
Else it is not permissible.

The mahrams are basically quoted in ([24:31](https://legacy.quran.com/24/31)):

> ... not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. ...

A woman may cut the hair of another woman (by hair I mean all kinds of hair not only that hair of the head only), but there are limitations based on the limitation of 'awrah between women or between women and men. Some of this is covered in the fatwa islamqa #[13744](https://islamqa.info/en/13744).

In summary when cutting the hair in general the rulings of 'awrah must be respected, if a person is allowed to look or touch the hair it is allowed if not it is forbidden.

See also islamqa #[22841](https://islamqa.info/en/22841)

Comment: Given a non-mahram woman is cutting a male non-mahram's hair, and we expect no inappropriate or lustful touching, shouldn't that be okay?

Comment: @EPICTubeHD it is not a matter of being "OK" nor "lust" simply.

Comment: So what exactly is it a matter of? Is it becuz it kinda gives immodest vibes when say a non-mahram is touching another non-mahram male's hair? Help me understand.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD the answer should make clear that it us a matter of "'awrah".

Comment: Oh I see, so in the last paragraph u mention "In summary when cutting the hair in general the rulings of 'awrah must be respected, if a person is allowed to look or touch the hair it is allowed if not it is forbidden." That means, if a male individual allows a non-mahram female to cut his hair, that should be okay? Since u also mention it's a matter of awrah, male's hair isn't part of the awrah.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD not really because there should be no touching between foreigners.